# Would this be an accurate method of fuel consumption comparison?

Tags: efficiency, fuel-consumption

I'm looking to compare the fuel consumption of regional jets in the US and the stated efficiency of the Bombardier CS100. At the moment, I'm considering using data from the Bureau of Transportation Statistics' Form 41 - T100D and T2. The T100D set provides the number of flights, distance, and aircraft type for each route and aircraft type. The T2 form provides overall fuel use by each aircraft type per airline.

I was considering plotting the average stage length for an aircraft type against the fuel used per seat nautical mile to arrive at a measure of efficiency as a function of stage length. I wanted to ask if this approach is methodologically accurate since I'm not entirely sure average stage lengths tell the entire story of how the aircraft is operated. If there are other models that could be more representative, could you point me in their direction?

My ultimate goal is to identify whether the CS100 could be more efficient than current jets. I've been looking at literature that estimates fuel use as a function of stage length and payload, but haven't had much success.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, then there is an easier route, which is the seat mileage, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_economy_in_aircraft#500%E2%80%93660_nautical_miles_(930%E2%80%931,220_km)).

Comment: @ymb1: Thanks so much for the link. Seems like I missed it when I searched around. While the numbers are right there, I was hoping to confirm them by using published data. The Wiki link does give me exactly the figures I'm looking to calculate, though.